# Solving an importing issue with selenium

Tags: python, facebook, selenium, bots, instagram

I am trying to write a simple bot that just logs into my Instagram for me and I have run into an issue installing Selenium for Chrome. 
I have run pip install Selenuim from the command line and it appears in the Python directory. I have then downloaded the chromedriver file from online and added it to my path. I then made a new script in my documents and wrote the following python:

```
    from selenuim import webdriver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("http://www.python.org")

    driver.close()
```

When I ran the program it gives the following error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Bot\Bot.py", line 2, in 
    from selenuim import webdriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenuim'

How to I get an installed module to import properly in python.

Thank you for helping.

EDIT: PLEASE DO NOT ANSWER THIS QUESTION I CANNOT SPELL

Comment: Pls check the spelling for 'selenium'!

Comment: please either delete the question, or accept the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You imported `selenuim`, It has a spelling mistake.

`selenium`

Comment: Great observation  :)

Answer (score 0):

You imported selenuim, It has a spelling mistake.

selenium

go your scripts path and install it in cmd.

C:\Users\vignesh.rajendran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts> pip install selenium

Check chrome.exe is present in the below path after installing selenium

C:\Users\vignesh.rajendran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\webbot\drivers